# Choosing the correct set of covariates (i.e. confounders) for inverse probability weighting

Tags: regression, feature-selection, causality, causalimpact

I use **inverse probability weighting (IPW)** to estimate the impact of a marketing intervention in the retail industry.  There is a test group of stores and a control group of stores, and the intervention is buy-one-get-one (BOGO) promotion for sneakers.  I have sales data starting from the first date of the BOGO promotion for 1 year.

I need to control for certain confounders, like

1. the size of the store
2. the median income of the store's neighborhood
3. the number of competitors in the store's trade area

Therefore, I control for these covariates in my model.

In my experience, ***the estimates of the intervention effect (in terms of impact and lift) swing wildly between different sets of covariates***. I can use my business knowledge to come up with plausible confounders (like the ones above), but I cannot be sure that I included all of them, or that I chose the correct ones.

**How, then, can I find the "correct" set of covariates in my IPW model**?  Is there some **diagnostic plot or statistic** that I can use to check this?

If it helps, please feel free to frame this question as a matter of model specification or variable selection.